# Making a new file using another as template in BASH

Tags: bash

I have two files such as:

File_1

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
```

File_2

```
c1,c3,c2,c4

DA,CA,DD,CD
```

Thus, I want to make a File 3 using the File 1 as model using BASH:

File_3

```
c1,c2,c3,c4

DA,DD,CA,CD
```

In this example, the File_1 is a model of the correct disposition of the columns and the File_2 has the columns and their respective informations but in a wrong disposition. Thus, the File_3 used the file_1 as a template and ordered the information in the file_2 in a correct disposition.

In the example I just gave 4 columns, but my real file has 402 columns.
So, to do an

```
awk -F"," '{print $1","$3","$2","$4}' File_2
```

or something like this, will not work because I dont know the position of the itens of the File_1 in the File_2 (for example the c1 column in the File_2 could be in the sixth, the second, or the last columns positions).

I hope that you can help me using BASH (if possible) and I would like an small explanation of the script, because I'm newbie and I don't know a lot the commands.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a header index mapping like this:

```
File_2  =>  File_1
------      ------
1       =>  1
2       =>  3
3       =>  2
4       =>  4
```

---

```
awk -F, '
    FNR==NR{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            a[$i]=i
        print
        nextfile
    }
    FNR==1{
        for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
            b[j]=a[$j]
        next
    }
    {
        for(k=1;k<=NF;k++)
            printf( "%s%s",$b[k], k==NF?"\n":",")
    }
' File_{1,2}
```

**Note:** This command works if `File_{1,2}` contain no empty lines!

Comment: Thanks Kev. It worked perfectly. I had more than 100,000 lines and worked as I wanted and quickly. What site do you encorajous me to read to understand the script?

Comment: Just basic `awk` stuff: `for...loop`, `printf`, `next/nextfile`, `NR/FNR`. I think you can understand them in several mins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to change the format of file 2 from:

```
File_2
c1,c3,c2,c4    
DA,CA,DD,CD
```

to:

```
s/c1/DA/g
s/c3/CA/g
s/c2/DD/g
s/c4/CD/g
```

you can use sed:

```
sed -f File_2 File_1 > File_3
```

Else you may work with arrays:

```
key=($(head -n1 File_2 | tr "," " "))
val=($(tail -n1 File_2 | tr "," " "))
len=${#key[*]}
for i in $(seq 0 $((len-1))); do echo s/${key[$i]}/${val[$i]}/g; done > subst.sed 
sed -f subst.sed File_1 > File_3
```

The generated sed-Program is the one as above. If a substitution matches the key of a following command, you might get unexpected results. If you only like to match whole words, you have to change the sed command a bit.